# building a pyparsing.Dict from a string of multiple tokens - part II

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've made some progress thanks to feedback from this forum ( thanks forum!).
The pyparsing.Dict object dict is getting populated but silently fails when it finds decimal numbers.

given:

```
import pyparsing as pp

lines = '''\
(rate multiple)
(region "mountainous")
(elev       21439)
(alteleva  +21439)
(altelevb  -21439)
(coorda  23899.747)
(coordb +23899.747)
(coordc -23899.747)
(coordd  853.324e21)
(coorde +853.324e21)
(coordf -853.324e21)
(coordg  987.88e+09)
(coordh +987.88e+09)
(coordi -987.88e+09)
(coordj  122.45e-04)
(coordk +122.45e-04)
(coordl -122.45e-04)
'''

leftParen    = pp.Literal('(')
rightParen   = pp.Literal(')')
colon        = pp.Literal(':')
decimalpoint = pp.Literal('.')
doublequote  = pp.Literal('"')
plusorminus  = pp.Literal('+') | pp.Literal('-') 
exp          = pp.CaselessLiteral('E')

v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
v_quoted_string = pp.Combine( doublequote + v_string + doublequote)
v_number = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?(?P<float1>\d+)(?P<float2>\.\d+)?(?P<float3>[Ee][+-]?\d+)?')

keyy = v_string
valu = v_string | v_quoted_string | v_number

item  = pp.Group( pp.Literal('(').suppress() + keyy + valu + pp.Literal(')').suppress() )
items = pp.ZeroOrMore( item)
dict = pp.Dict( items)

print "dict yields: ",  dict.parseString( lines).dump()
```

yields

```
- alteleva: '+21439',
- altelevb: '-21439',
- elev: '21439',
- rate: 'multiple',
- region: '"mountainous"'
```

Changing the order of tokens around proves the script silently fails when it hits the first decimal number, which implies there's something subtly wrong with the pp.Regex statement but I sure can't spot it.

TIA,

code_warrior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem actually lies in this expression:

```
valu = v_string | v_quoted_string | v_number
```

Because `v_string` is defined as the very broadly-matching expression:

```
v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
```

and because it is the first expression in `valu`, it will mask `v_numbers` that start with a digit. This is because the '|' operator produces `pp.MatchFirst` objects, so the first expression matched (reading left-to-right) will determine which alternative is used. You can convert to using the '^' operator, which produces `pp.Or` objects - the `Or` class will try to evaluate all the alternatives and then go with the *longest* match. However, note that using `Or` carries a performance penalty, since many more expressions are test for a match even when there is no chance for confusion. In your case, you can just reorder the expressions to put the least specific matching expression last:

```
valu = v_quoted_string | v_number | v_string
```

Now values will be parsed first attempting to parse as quoted strings, then as numbers, and then only if there is no match for either of these specific types, as the very general type `v_string`.

A few other comments:

I personally prefer to parse quoted strings and only get the content within the quotes (It's a string, I know it already!). There used to be some confusion with older versions of pyparsing when dumping out the parsed results when parsed strings were displayed without any enclosing quotes. But now that I use repr() to show the parsed values, strings show up in quotes when calling `dump()`, but the value itself does not include the quotes. When it is used elsewhere in the program, such as saving to a database or CSV, I don't need the quotes, I just want the string content. The `QuotedString` class takes care of this for me by default. Or use `pp.quotedString().addParseAction(pp.removeQuotes)`.

A recent pyparsing release introduced the `pyparsing_common` namespace class, containing a number of helpful pre-defined expressions. There are several for parsing different numeric types (integer, signed integer, real, etc.), and a couple of blanket expressions: `number` will parse any numeric type, and produce values of the respective type (`real` will give a float, `integer` will give an int, etc.); `fnumber` will parse various numerics, but return them all as floats. I've replaced your `v_number` expression with just `pp.pyparsing_common.number()`, which also permits me to remove several other partial expressions that were defined just for building up the `v_number` expression, like `decimalpoint`, `plusorminus` and `exp`. You can see more about the expressions in `pyparsing_common` at the online docs: https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/

Pyparsing's default behavior when processing literal strings in an expression like `"(" + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + valu + ")"` is to automatically convert the literal "(" and ")" terms to `pp.Literal` objects. This prevents accidentally losing parsed data, but in the case of punctuation, you end up with many cluttering and unhelpful extra strings in the parsed results. In your parser, you can replace pyparsing's default by calling `pp.ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing` and passing the `pp.Suppress` class:

```
pp.ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(pp.Suppress)
```

Now you can write an expression like:

```
item  = pp.Group('(' + keyy + valu + ')')
```

and the grouping parentheses will be suppressed from the parsed results.

Making these changes, your parser now simplifies to:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# override pyparsing default to suppress literal strings in expressions
pp.ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(pp.Suppress)

v_string = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
v_quoted_string = pp.QuotedString('"')
v_number = pp.pyparsing_common.number()

keyy = v_string
# define valu using least specific expressions last
valu = v_quoted_string | v_number | v_string

item  = pp.Group('(' + keyy + valu + ')')
items = pp.ZeroOrMore( item)
dict_expr = pp.Dict( items)

print ("dict yields: ",  dict_expr.parseString( lines).dump())
```

And for your test input, gives:

```
dict yields:  [['rate', 'multiple'], ['region', 'mountainous'], ['elev', 21439], 
['alteleva', 21439], ['altelevb', -21439], ['coorda', 23899.747], ['coordb', 
23899.747], ['coordc', -23899.747], ['coordd', 8.53324e+23], ['coorde', 
8.53324e+23], ['coordf', -8.53324e+23], ['coordg', 987880000000.0], ['coordh', 
987880000000.0], ['coordi', -987880000000.0], ['coordj', 0.012245], ['coordk', 
0.012245], ['coordl', -0.012245]]
- alteleva: 21439
- altelevb: -21439
- coorda: 23899.747
- coordb: 23899.747
- coordc: -23899.747
- coordd: 8.53324e+23
- coorde: 8.53324e+23
- coordf: -8.53324e+23
- coordg: 987880000000.0
- coordh: 987880000000.0
- coordi: -987880000000.0
- coordj: 0.012245
- coordk: 0.012245
- coordl: -0.012245
- elev: 21439
- rate: 'multiple'
- region: 'mountainous'
```

Comment: using pp.Or did indeed solve the problem, a subtle one. Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed response, I learned alot from it.